# Asynchronous service that publishes a possibly infinite amount of events

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, rx-java

I want to implement a service that fetches eyetracking events and publishes them to all subscribers of the stream. The whole thing is supposed to run asynchronously, so it doesn't block the UI thread. This is how the service is supposed to be used:

```
ETStreamService service = new ETStreamService();
service.getObservable().subscribe(e -> ...);
service.start();
doSomeOtherWork();
service.stop();
```

I implemented a generic version (error handling omitted):

```
public class ETStreamService<E extends ChronologicComparable<E>> {

    private ETReceiver<E> receiver;
    private AtomicBoolean running;
    private PublishSubject<E> publishSubject;
    private Thread streamThread;

    private class ETStreamRunnable implements Runnable {
        private ETReceiver<E> receiver;
        private AtomicBoolean running;
        private PublishSubject<E> publishSubject;

        public ETStreamRunnable(AtomicBoolean running, ETReceiver<E> receiver, PublishSubject<E> publishSubject) {
            this.receiver = receiver;
            this.running = running;
            this.publishSubject = publishSubject;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(running.get()) {
                ETResponse<E> response = receiver.getNext();

                switch(response.getType()) {
                case NEW_DATA:
                    publishSubject.onNext(response.getData());
                    break;
                case NO_NEW_DATA_AVAILABLE:
                    break;
                case SOURCE_DEPLETED:
                    publishSubject.onComplete();
                    running.set(false);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public ETStreamService(ETReceiver<E> receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.running = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        this.publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    }

    public void start() {
        running.set(true);
        streamThread = new Thread(new ETStreamRunnable(running, receiver, publishSubject));
        streamThread.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        running.set(false);
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        running.set(false);
        publishSubject.onComplete();
    }

    public Observable<E> getObservable() {
        return publishSubject;
    }
}
```

The idea is to run a separate thread, which can be started and stopped through the public interface of the `ETStreamService` class. The Runnable that is run inside the thread does the fetching and publishing of events. The event stream can be obtained by calling `getObservable()`. `onComplete()` is emitted if the `ETReceiver` has no more elements to receive (finite source, like a list of pre-recorded data), or if the `shutdown()` method is called (for infinite sources, such as a real eyetracker).

I like the overall design, but i am unsure about the thread safety of it, so it would be nice if someone could review it for me.